# Randomly choose a word from a text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to do my assignment for college, and no where can i find a way to read from a text file and choose a random word from the list! The assignment is about hangman, and the program is suppose to choose a random word from the list

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Hangman extends JFrame
{
int i = 0;
static JPanel panel;
static JPanel panel2;
static JPanel panel3;

public Hangman()
{
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[26];

panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,9));
panel2 = new JPanel();
panel3 = new JPanel();

JButton btnRestart = new JButton("Restart");
btnRestart.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    }
});

JButton btnNewWord = new JButton("Add New Word");
btnNewWord.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
try
{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Words.txt", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);

    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a word: ");

    pw.println(word);
    pw.close();
}
catch(IOException ie)
{
    System.out.println("Error Thrown" + ie.getMessage());
}
}
});

JButton btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
btnHelp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
       String message = "The word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, giving the number of letters and category of the word. \nIf the guessing player suggests a letter which occurs in the word, the other player writes it in all its correct positions. \nIf the suggested letter does not occur in the word, the other player draws one element of the hangman diagram as a tally mark."
               + "\n"
               + "\nThe game is over when:"
               + "\nThe guessing player completes the word, or guesses the whole word correctly"
               + "\nThe other player completes the diagram";
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message, "Help",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
});

JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("D:\\Varsity College\\Prog212Assign1_10-013803\\images\\Hangman1.jpg");
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(icon);
String  b[]={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
    buttons[i] = new JButton(b[i]);

    panel.add(buttons[i]);
}

panel2.add(label);

panel3.add(btnRestart);
panel3.add(btnNewWord);
panel3.add(btnHelp);
panel3.add(btnExit);
}
public void readFromFile()
{
try
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt"));
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Hangman frame = new Hangman();
    Box mainPanel = Box.createVerticalBox();
    frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(panel2);
    mainPanel.add(panel3);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest loading the possible words into a `List` and using [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) to generate a random order which you can then sample from.

Answer (score 4):

Create a method to read the file's words into the `List`. For e.g:

```
List<String> words = readFile();
```

To get the words use `String#split(" ")` to split the line into the words. Add those words into the list. Then just use:

```
Random yourRandom = new Random(words.size());
String word = words.get(yourRandom.nextInt());
```

And you'll get the random word from your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ReadLine()` function to read each line from the text file. This will return a string that you can use with `fileLine.split(" ")`. This will give you an array with each element as a word in the file.

If you add all of these of a List you can then get the size and select a random number between  0 and `size()`, then use this to get the String for the collection.

You now have a random word from the file that you just read in.

Sample Code:

```
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt"));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(line != null) {
        String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");
        for(String word : wordsLine) {
            words.add(word);
        }
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String randomWord = words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle this
}
```

Comment: Words are one per line, so no need for the `line.split`

Comment: @veer Thanks, fixed the code snippet. The split can be removed if you can guarantee that there will not be multiple words on one line.

Comment: Given the following statement `pw.println(word);` from the OP I'm going to assume that yes the split can be removed. :-)

Comment: @JaunLloyd What about it isn't working, are you seeing errors or not getting the correct output? If you can be more specific we can try and give you some help.

Comment: No I finally got it to work, i used the code you gave me, but instead of using a void i used a string and thus a return value.... thanks for the help i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief guide on how this could be approached:

Read to array, using, say a Scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
while(scanner.hasNext()){
  // add scanner.nextLine() words to array 
}
```

After the array has been populated, you can shuffle prior to picking a word:

```
Collections.shuffle(wordList);
String pickWord = wordList.get(0);
```

I'm using the first entry in the list here, but you could pick a random one.

Comment: You can shuffle once for multiple random selections, too, given that every element is as random as the first :-)